# How I show the top of the page in webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I mean when I am end of the page in android webview how I show top of the page? 
Think I have a button and when I click it , show top of the page in webview.
Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a better answer to this issue. It turns out that WebView does have scrollTo(), getScrollX() and getScrollY() methods as you'd expect. They're a bit hidden in the documentation because they're inherited from View (via AbsoluteLayout -> ViewGroup -> View). This is obviously a better way to manipulate the WebView's scroll position than the somewhat cumbersome JavaScript interface.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this as I have yet to encounter this problem, but perhaps you could overrive the onScroll function?

```
@Override
public void scrollTo(int x, int y){
    super(0,y);
}
```